# BigDump.php error

Tags: php, wordpress

After importing a large SQL file on wordpress environment using Bigdump.php script, i am getting the following error. (Though the import was successful.)

Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in /home/shag/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/functions.php on line 60
WordPress database error: [Table 'shag_wp.wp_datalist' doesn't exist]
SELECT count(*) FROM `wp_datalist` WHERE `url` = "/"

How can i fix this?

[This is the site.](http://shag.me)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It tells you? _use mysql_real_escape_string() instead._

Comment: Check your database files and use find and replace method to resolve this function issue.

Comment: @Vinay Can you shell some more light on how i can fix this, though i do have access to phpMyAdmin. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a warning, not an error.

But the whole mysql extension has been deprecated since 2013 - meaning that you are running on a very old version of PHP. This will have a major impact on the security of your site.

Do you plan to make a habit of regularly importing large datasets? What are you planning to do about upgrading your PHP (and if its so old, then probably your DBMS, Wordpress and OS are long overdue for an upgrade too).

The problem you are reporting in itself has no real impact, but how best to address it depends on how how you intend to address the other problems you haven't asked us about.

Comment: Upgraded to newer version of PHP and WordPress helped to resolve the issue.